# Power automate: JSON formatting issues

Tags: arrays, json, arraylist, power-automate

I am using excel to generate a JSON file via a power automate flow. I have most of the functionality working but am stuck on a formatting issue where lists are being outputted as objects.

This is the format I need:
`"_source" : { "title" : null, "first_name" : { "value" : "Tony", "source" : "48fa2a08-9137-49fa-8a7d-1d85570b7e5d" }, "last_name" : { "value" : "Stark", "source" : "48fa2a08-9137-49fa-8a7d-1d85570b7e5d" }, "full_name" : "Tony Stark",...`

This is the format I am getting:
`"_source": { "title": null, "first_name": [ { "value": "Tony", "source": "48fa2a08-9137-49fa-8a7d-1d85570b7e5d" } ], "last_name": [ { "value": "Stark", "source": "48fa2a08-9137-49fa-8a7d-1d85570b7e5d" } ], "full_name": ["Tony Stark"],...`

I am composing this in the following way:

[image]

How do I get rid of the square brackets?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. TIA

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You mean values are being output as arrays. It’s a simple first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `output` result of your data operations for (e.g.) `first_name` is an array.

In order to remove the square brackets, you need to drill down and get the item you want from the array.

Typically, an array is an array because you potentially expect more than one item to exist but in your case, it looks like that’s all you expect, therefore, you need to use an expression that will get the first item in the array.

To do that, you can wrap the “Output” from the Data Operations step (whatever that action actually is) in a `first()` expression.

That will return the first object in your array and remove the square brackets.